# Converting php variables to Excel

Tags: php, excel

I have php code as follows:

```
<?php
    $bkimgsrc='images/BGcovers/image.jpg';
        $bktitle='My Book';
        $bkISBN='000-1-555555-36-6';
        $price='$9.99';
        $bkdesc='This is all about me';
        $ebook='y';
        $epub='999';
        $mobi='666';
        include 'book.php';     ?>
```

There may be several of these segments in one file (more than one book).

I would like to somehow run a procedure or grep to get all of these fields into an excel database. I've got at least 50 files to run through, so copy and paste is going to be a bear. Can anyone point me to an app or a script or a piece of code that I can run?

Comment: Loop and include each file and https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Comment: But these fields are not in an array. They are just variables.

Comment: You create an array using those.  There isn't enough info about what else is in the file and if all files have the same variables names etc...

Comment: All files have the same variables. I do not want to rewrite all of the files to contain arrays. I want a simple method of extracting the variables into a text, cvs, or excel file.

Comment: That's what I gave you `fputcsv ($handle, [$bkimgsrc, $bktitle, etc...]);`

Comment: This requires me using the function in every file. I want to open the directory, scan for .php files (I can manage those two steps) and then search through each file for the contents of these variables.

Comment: Do your first two steps, then loop through the files and `include` the file.  Then those variables will be available to write to the csv, then the next file is included and those variables are overwritten and you write them out to the csv, etc...

Comment: And when there is more than one instance of the variable in a file? More than one book?